# Get printers installed from server from remote computer using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script in powershell that will get all the installed printers in each computer.
At my organization we use a print server running win server 2019 to manage and share all the printers.
For some reason the commands
Get-Printer and win32_Printer return only the locally installed printers (which are the windows defaults like ms print to pdf).
I've tried to run the lines on the server itself and got the full list cause they are installed locally.
Is there a way the get a printer that was installed from a server? And in the future I will also want to install and uninstall those printers via powershell.

Comment: What do you get using `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_Printer -ComputerName $arrayOfComputerNames`"Each of these objects have a whealth of properties. Interesting in this case are `Local` (true of false) and `Network`

Comment: @Theo - That only seems to get the local printers, same as `Get-Printer`.

Comment: Usually printers are installed per-user (in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`), so trying to retrieve those remotely is sort of meaningless. It depends on what is your purpose/goal (why do you need this information, and what will you do with the information once you have it?).

Answer (score 0):

I have a function that does this, specifically, for our environment, but it relies on several other "self-coded" functions, so I'm not going to paste it here.

What you need to do is connect to the registry on the remote computer and interrogate it. The subkeys for `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Connections` are GUIDs, and interrogating the `PRINTER` property of each of those subkeys will give you the UNC pathname of the connected printer.

This does NOT return the locally-defined printers; for that, you need `Get-Printer`.

Comment: Thanks!
I've tried to explore it and eventually found what I was looking for at
HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Print\Providers\Client Side Rendering Print Provider\Servers\SERVER_NAME\Printers\*

Could you pls guide me about how to install/uninstall a printer with this info?